# Do running applications and background processes have any effects on Power Consumption?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, battery-life

I need some help with android applications: Do running applications and background processes have any effects on Power Consumption of the Battery (running down so fast)?

Comment: Please take a look at our [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info), which will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Yes" through my own observations.  Apps like live wallpapers do have an effect on  battery life.  Add to that any active radios like WiFi, Bluetooth, GPS, Mobile data and battery life can go down the tubes.  I have learned to disable things if I am not able to charge right away or need a bit more battery life.  I would also like to mention about running apps and background processes, I would suggest not disabling them unless you know what you are doing.